# Скрипт всплывающего окна не по id

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток

```
// подключаем JQ
// подключаем кое какой скрипт - popup.js
// содержимое которого:
function PopUp(obj,trig){
    var html = obj.html();
    obj.remove();
    var body = $('body')[0];

    var HTML="<div id='popup'><span id='cancel'></span>"+html+"</div>";
    var win = $('<div id="win">'+HTML+'</div>');
    win.appendTo(body);

    function showWin(){
        $('#win').css({display: 'block'});
        $('#popup').css({
            display:'block', 
            opacity:0, 
            top: $(window).height()/2-$('#popup').height()/2+'px', 
            left: $(window).width()/2-$('#popup').width()/2+'px'
        });
        $('#popup').css('opacity', 1);          
    }

    if($(trig)){
        $(trig).click(function(){
            showWin();
        });
    }

    if($('#cancel')){
        $('#cancel').click(function(){
            $('#win').css('display', 'none');
        });
    }

}
// внутри страницы пишу следующее
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    PopUp($('#obj'), $('#trigg'));
});
</script>

//ну и на странице где хочу пишу код, для всплывающего сообщения:
echo "<a id=\"trigg\" href=\"javascript:void(0);\"><center>text</center><br></a>";//ссылка
echo "<div id=\"obj\"><div class=\"sample\"><center>text2</center></div></div>";//само окно
```

Пример рабочий. К сожалению не совместим с многими JS скриптами потому, что использует id. Вот можно ли как то в место id использовать что либо другое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменить `id` на `class` пробовал?

Comment: нет. сейчас попробую